# Does Elixir allow defstruct to call a function defined in the same module?

Tags: elixir

I have a module that looks something like this:

```
defmodule Othello.Game do
  alias Othello.Game, as: Game
  alias Othello.Utils, as: Utils

  defstruct enabled_spaces: Utils.gen_list(Game.width() * Game.width(), fn _ -> false end),
            is_game_over: false,
            is_first_player: true

  def width(), do: 8
end
```

Is it possible to call the *width()* function from with the *defstruct*?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ both calls to `alias` might be shortened to `alias Othello.{Game,Utils}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not be possible as the `module` that is defining the `struct` still needs to get compiled in order for its functions to work as you can see from the example below:

```
iex(1)> defmodule A do
...(1)> def a, do: 1
...(1)> defstruct a: __MODULE__.a()
...(1)> end
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function A.a/0 is undefined (function a/0 is not available)
    A.a()
    iex:3: (module)
```

**Alternative**: define a module attribute and use that instead:

```
defmodule Othello.Game do
  @width 8
  alias Othello.Game, as: Game
  alias Othello.Utils, as: Utils

  defstruct enabled_spaces: Utils.gen_list(@width * @width, fn _ -> false end),
            is_game_over: false,
            is_first_player: true

  def width(), do: @width
end
```